# Automatic Mount at Boot For Xubuntu

Tags: boot, hard-disk, automounting, xubuntu

I'm trying to follow these instruction to mount a second hard drive:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallingANewHardDrive

For automatic mount at boot it says I need to enter this into the terminal:

```
sudo nano -Bw /etc/fstab
```

Then:

Add this line to the end (for ext3 file system):

```
  /dev/sdb1    /media/mynewdrive   ext3    defaults     0        2
```

Add this line to the end (for fat32 file system):

```
  /dev/sdb1    /media/mynewdrive   vfat    defaults     0        2
```

I'm not really sure what file system I am working with.  I'm also not sure what it means to add the line to the end.  End of what?
This is a screen shot of what happens when I type in "sudo nano -Bw /etc/fstab"

https://i.stack.imgur.com/eHUC3.png

Answer (score 0):

...to the end of /etc/fstab file obviously!
These were probably just two lines to mount device /dev/sdb1 containing either Linux file system (ext3) or Windows file system (vfat). You have to leave just one line in your /etc/fstab. But first you have to find out what is the device you are trying to mount (from your screenshot it looks like /dev/sda). If it is empty non-partitioned hard drive, you have to create partitions first, e.g. with

```
fdisk /dev/sda
```

and then format it with e.g.

```
mkfs.vfat /dev/sda1
```

to format 1st partition of /dev/sda to vfat (windows fat32 filesystem)

Only then you can mount it.... 
/etc/fstab record is needed only if you want to automount the drive. But first try to mount it manually, e.g. to /media/mydrive (which must exist):

```
mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /media/mydrive
```

Comment: The hard drive that I'm trying to mount is not empty, it's has files on it from when my computer ran windows (I don't care if I keep these files or not because I backed them up to another external hard drive).  Should I just skip to the step you listed "mount -t vfat /dev/sda1 /media/mydrive" ?

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded Ubuntu's disk utility, and it was easier for me to figure out how to mount the hard drive through GUI.

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-disk-utility
```

Answer (score 0):

> If you are new to file systems and partitioning, please do some >preliminary research on the two before you attempt this procedure.

The descriptions in the link are good, and this is a good advice. You have to so special commands with special system tools.

> I'm not really sure what file system I am working with.

and:

> (I don't care if I keep these files or not because I backed them up to >another external hard drive).

The ubuntu link explains quite well how many different options you have. No installation tool can decide for you how to label (gpt, dos) partition (a1, a2, ...; b1, b2, b3...) and format (ext4, FAT,...).

Answer (score 0):

Based on your screenshot, it looks like the system was installed on /dev/sdb and you are adding /dev/sda.  Usually a system is installed on /dev/sda and the second disk is /dev/sdb, so you could quickly just try to use /dev/sda1 instead to try mounting the first/only partition of the new drive.

For anything else, follow these instructions.

To mount a partition on your filesystem, you need to have:

1. An identifier for the partition
2. A directory for mounting the partition
3. The filesystem type (i.e. how was it formatted?)

In the example you have given, the partition is identified as /dev/sdb1 which indicates the first partition of disk sdb.  But that might not be the right partition in your case. You can get a list of all disks and partitions using fdisk:

```
sudo fdisk -l
```

This will list all your disks, plus the partitions.  Once you have identified the right partition (sdX#) you want to mount, and have your mount directory (/media/newdisk) created, then simply try to mount before adding to fstab:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdX# /media/newdisk
```

You can now use the mount command without options to see how this partition was mounted:

```
mount
```

That should provide you with enough information to add a line to fstab, including the filesystem type.  An fstab line takes the format:

```
<DEVICE> <MOUNTPOINT> <FS TYPE> <OPTIONS> <DUMP #> <PASS #>
```

The example sounds fine for your usage after identifying the first 3 items.  Do 'man mount' to see more about the options.

Note that in your screenshot, the UUID=XXXXXXXXXXXX are used to identify the device instead of a path to /dev/sdX#.  If you would rather use that format, you can get the UUID for the partition using blkid:

```
blkid /dev/sdX#
```

/etc/fstab will support both formats, but UUID will guarantee that line always corresponds to the same partition.